# What is the file path to the data directory of the latest version of PostgreSQL installed in my mac?

Tags: postgresql

There are two versions of PostgreSQL installed in my Mac: 9.6 and 10.1. Currently, when I use the psql command, it's using 10.1 version of the database. I want to figure out the location of the data directory for the latest version. The following command returns the filepath for the version 9.6, not 10.1.

```
ps auxwww | grep postmaster
```

What should my terminal command be to get the data directory of the latest version?

Comment: Start `psql`, login as the superuser (to the running version 10), run `show data_directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html

> PG_VERSION    A file containing the major version number of PostgreSQL

so to find all possible `$PGDATA`, run as root:

```
find / -name PG_VERSION
```